# Tasker and Secure Settings 'not found' error

Tags: android

In Tasker for Android, the %EFROM variable is set to the last email's FROM field.
I want to write a command to get only the name from it, not the address.

So I tried using the `Run Command` in `Secure Settings` plugin, writing:

```
echo "%EFROM" | sed "s/ *<.*//"
```

and I get an error:

```
<stdin>[1]: sed: not found
```

I tried with `grep` and `cut` instead of `sed`, without luck. If I write simply

```
echo "%EFROM"
```

I don't get errors, but I get the usual content of `%EFROM`, of course.

Then I tried to add the full path of `sed` in front of it. Now I don't get errors, but it just does not filter anything, giving back the original string.

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks!!

L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, by adding `busybox` in front of `sed`. 
Not sure why it is needed, though. I found several places on the Internet that don't need busybox. Maybe you should inform Tasker where busybox is or something...